# JS Удалить Div по нажатию кнопки в модальном окне

Tags: javascript

Есть список дивов при наведении на которые появляеться кнопка удаления при нажатии на которую появляеться модальное окно с просьбой подтвердить удаление. Если позьзователь подтвержадает удаление то должен удаляться тот див в котором было вызванно данное модальное окно, подскажите пожалуйста как это можно реализовать
[image: примерная схема]

Comment: код свой покажите

Comment: Ну давайте пойдём опытным путём, что вы попробовали сделать и что у вас не получается?

Comment: Модальное окно реализовано с помощью bootstrap 3 я не понимаю как на кнопке в модальном окне сказать что должен удаляться тот див в котором было вызвано собственно модальное окно

Answer (score 1):

```js
$(".del_div button").on("click", function() {
  $(".modal").show()
  divs_id = $(this).closest(".del_div").attr('id')
})
$(".modal button").on("click", function() {
  $("#" + divs_id).remove()
  $(".modal").hide()
})
```

```css
.del_div {
  border: 1px solid;
}

.modal {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="del_div" id="1">
  <p>text 1</p>
  <button>удалить</button>
</div>
<div class="del_div" id="2">
  <p>text 2</p>
  <button>удалить</button>
</div>

<div class="del_div" id="3">
  <p>text 3</p>
  <button>удалить</button>
</div>

<div class="del_div" id="4">
  <p>text 4</p>
  <button>удалить</button>
</div>

<div class="modal">
  <p>Точно удалить?</p>
  <button>да</button>
</div>
```

Какой-то такой вариант ¯_(ツ)_/¯

Answer (score 0):

Например так:

```
<div>
   <div onClick="confirmDelete(this)">Первый</div>
   <div onClick="confirmDelete(this)">Второй</div>
   <div onClick="confirmDelete(this)">Третий</div>
</div>

<script>
    function confirmDelete(item)
    {
       // показываем модалку 
       // да, удалить!
       item.remove();
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
document.querySelectorAll ('div').forEach (div => div.querySelector ('button').addEventListener ('click', ev => confirm ('Are you sure?') && div.parentNode.removeChild (div)))
```

```html
<div>1<button>Delete</button></div>
<div>2<button>Delete</button></div>
<div>3<button>Delete</button></div>
```